# MySQL data on PHP Table - Online status different color label

Tags: php, mysql, label

Currently I am using this script

```
<?php
$servername = "**CENCERED**";
$username = "**CENCERED**";
$password = "**CENCERED**";
$dbname = "**CENCERED**";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT userID, users_name, usertype, status FROM tbluseraccounts";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "ID: " . $row["userID"]. " <br> Name: " . $row["users_name"]. " <br> Account Type: " . $row["usertype"]. " <br> Status: " . $row["status"]. "<br>";
}
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

How can I add to the code so when $row["status"] say "Online" my text will be green or when it says "Offline" It will turn Red.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your while loop you can do something like

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    if($row["status"] == "Online"){
        $tcolor = "green";
    }
    elseif($row["status"] == "Offline"){
        $tcolor = "red";
    }
    echo "ID: " . $row["userID"]. " <br> Name: " . $row["users_name"]. " <br> Account Type: " . $row["usertype"]. " <br> Status: <font color='".$tcolor."'>" . $row["status"]. "</font><br>";
}
```

Hope this can give you some idea.

Comment: This almost works except for all the text changes red http://graphicambi.tk/onlineemployees.html How can this be fixed?

Comment: I guess that is because they are offline? And that is what I have seen in the link given.

Comment: or do you want only particular text to change to red, not all change to red?

Comment: only the text saying "offline" being red and the text saying "online" to be green lol

Comment: please refer the updated answer. Note that I moved the `<font>` and surround the status text.